# select a pair from an SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select a pair of supplier ID that meets a certain requirement, i.e. the first supplier charges more than the second one for a certain part.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S1.sid, S2.sid
FROM suppliers JOIN catalog ON (suppliers.sid = catalog.sid) AS S1,
suppliers JOIN catalog ON (suppliers.sid = catalog.sid) AS S2
WHERE S1.pid = S2.pid AND S1.cost > S2.cost;
```

Now this isn't working. Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "this isn't working" means?

Comment: Here is the error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: ...pliers join catalog on(suppliers.sid=catalog.sid) as S1, sup...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"

Comment: Are you trying some sort of conditional JOIN?Show some sample data.

Comment: It'd really help if you'd accompanied the SQL with some sample data (`create table` and `insert` statements, or at least a text table of data) to show what the query acts on. Please also include your PostgreSQL version (`select version()`) in questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in the way you expresses the joins: the table on the left (i.e. `suppliers`) does not need to be repeated for each table being added to the query.

Here is how you can fix the query using table aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S1.sid, S2.sid 
FROM suppliers s
JOIN catalog s1 ON s.sid=s1.sid
JOIN catalog s2 ON s.sid=s2.sid 
WHERE S1.pid=S2.pid AND S1.cost>S2.cost
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your query is that you have the same table multiple times in the `from` clause without table aliases to distinguish among the different references.

Here is a different approach that uses a CTE to combine `suppliers` and `catalogs` and then a simple join:

```
with sc as (
      select s1.sid, pid, cost
      from suppliers s1 join
           catalog c1
           on s1.sid = c1.sid
     )
select distinct sc1.sid, sc2.sid
from sc sc1 join
     sc sc2
     on sc1.pid = sc2.pid and sc1.cost > sc2.cost;
```

This request seems like an odd request -- if you have multiple suppliers for a given part, you will get many rows.

EDIT:

It strikes me that you don't even need the `suppliers` table at all:

```
select distinct c1.sid, c2.sid
from catalog c1 join
     catalog c2
     on c1.pid = c2.pid and c1.cost > c2.cost;
```